# Handling network timeouts with Node and Axios

Tags: node.js, axios, timeout

I have this function that sends an http request using axios

```
  async sendRequest(data) {
    const config = { timeout: 1 };
    const postData = querystring.stringify({ data: data });

    return axios.post(url, postData, config);
  }
```

Then in my main code I do this

```
  try {
    const response = await sendRequest(data);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED') {
       // Do something ...
    }
  }
```

I know the above example will work. By setting the timeout time in the Axios call, I know that the error code in case of timeout will be ECONNABORTED, so in that case it is easy to catch it.

What happens if, for example I don't specify the timeout attribute in my axios call, something like this:

```
  async sendRequest(data) {
    const postData = querystring.stringify({ data: data });

    return axios.post(url, postData, {});
  }
```

But the server where I send the request to, returns a timeout error ? 
How do I catch it in this case ?

Comment: It will depend what your server does on a timeout.  You will see a different error if the server just drops the connection vs. if the server sends a 4xx or 5xx error.  In all three cases, the default behavior for axios should be that it rejects it's promise and gives you an error code.  You will have to test your particular server to see what it does.  If you don't know how to simulate that problem with your server, then you will just have to code defensively without knowing exactly what type of error will come back and make sure all possible errors have a reasonable code path.

Comment: FYI, a well-behaved server would probably give you a 408 response (Request Timeout), but something like an intervening proxy, firewall or load balancer might just drop the connection.

Comment: FYI, if the server is a vanilla nodejs http server or Express server, then per a test I ran, when it hits the server-side timeout, you will get `ECONNRESET` as the error.  The browser itself also has a timeout value (I don't know how long it is) so depending upon which one is hit first, you may get a different error.